# .NET Core API : No route matches the supplied values

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest

i'm making a Web API and i want to retrieve the object created by the CreateCommand Method.

To do that, I'm using the `CreateAtRoute` function to call the `GetCommandById` function ,with the id of the created `Command` as parameter, but i'm getting the following error:

> " System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied
> values."

This is my controller:

```
[Route("api/commands")]
[ApiController]
public class CommandsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICommanderRepo _repository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public CommandsController(ICommanderRepo repository,IMapper mapper)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult <IEnumerable<CommandReadDto>> GetAllCommands()
    {
        var commands = _repository.GetAllCommands();
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CommandReadDto>>(commands));
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult <CommandReadDto> GetCommandById(int id)
    {
        var command = _repository.GetCommandById(id);

        if(command != null)
        {
            return Ok(_mapper.Map<CommandReadDto>(command));
        }
        return NotFound();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult <CommandReadDto> CreateCommand(CommandCreateDto commandCreateDto)
    {
        var commandModel = _mapper.Map<Command>(commandCreateDto);
        _repository.CreateCommand(commandModel);
        _repository.SaveChanges();

        var commandReadDto = _mapper.Map<CommandReadDto>(commandModel);
        var x = nameof(GetCommandById);
        return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetCommandById), new { id = commandReadDto.Id }, commandReadDto);
    }
```

I have already tried this (which didn't resolve the problem):

1. Check if the parameters of both functions match
2. Added to my Startup.cs : `services.AddControllers(options => options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false);`  ( i saw this on a post here in stackoverflow

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `CreatedAtRoute`, you'll need something like shown below. Please note the addition of a route name, and use of that route name in `CreatedAtRoute`.

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name="GetCommand")]
public ActionResult <CommandReadDto> GetCommandById(int id)
{
   ... // your code here
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult <CommandReadDto> CreateCommand(CommandCreateDto commandCreateDto)
{
    ... // your code here

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetCommand", new { commandReadDto.Id }, commandReadDto);
}
```

An alternative, is to use `CreatedAtAction` like shown below. With this approach, a route name is not required.

```
return CreatedAtAction("GetCommandById", new { commandReadDto.Id }, commandReadDto);
```

You should derive your API-controllers from `ControllerBase` instead of `Controller`. The latter is targeting MVC-controllers.

And I believe you should remove `options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames` until you actually need it.